# Backreferences to capturing group instead of captured result

Tags: c#, ip, backreference

I want to use regular expression to check whether a given string is an IP address or not. My first idea was `^([0-2][0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.\1\.\1\.\1$`, but then I remembered that backreferences are referencing to the result of the capturing group. So my solution would work for IP adresses like `192.192.192.192`, `168.168.168.168` or `178.178.178.178`. **Is there another type of backreference that references to the regex of a capturing group instead of referencing to a result of the capturing group?** Is there a better way than using `([0-2][0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.` four times in a row? Or does the .NET Framework offer functions to check strings whether they are IPs or not?

Comment: You could say that my question is a duplicate, but I think I ask some more things, didn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

[IPAddress.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx)

Comment: Sounds logically, but this functions sees strings like `192` or `192.168` as IPs and returns true for them.

Comment: @Cubinator73 Read the comments in the answer linked. You can also combine above method with, for ex, `192.168.1.1".Count(x => x == '.') == 3;`